# pull string linux java

Tags: java, linux

How can I pull only the string from a line irrespective of the position in Linux?

Example :

I want to pull the `-Xmx` and `-Xms` values of Java from multiple Linux boxes where the position of the strings are not same.

Comment: • Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take some time to follow the [Stack Overflow tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Also provide us the relevant code you wrote (and at least what you've tried so far) for your question (You can also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: Are these heap settings saved in scripts used to start a java program? If so, why not use grep: ssh [USER-NAME]@[REMOTE-HOST] grep "-Xm." /path/to/script/script.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `grep` command (you can [read the documentation here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-use-grep-command-in-linux-unix/)).

For example, if the file "*file.txt*" constains the following:

```
setting1: value1
setting2: value2
setting3: value3
...
```

The command `grep setting2 file.txt` would return:

```
$ grep setting2 file.txt
    setting2: value2
```

If more there were more than one setting named `setting2`, it would return one line per each.